# Drawing STL with OpenGl and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, opengl

I am trying to port a program from Python2 to Python3. Everything is fine with Python2.

OpenGl returns an error when trying to draw the object. Here is the function:

```
        def draw_facets(self):
            glPushMatrix()
    
            # Ligthing, color and Material Stuff
            ...
            ### VBO stuff
            glBegin(GL_LINES)

            #   THE ERROR COMES FROM THAT POINT
            self.vertex_buffer.bind()
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
            self.normal_buffer.bind()
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
            glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(self.vertices))
    
            glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
            self.normal_buffer.unbind()
            self.vertex_buffer.unbind()
    
            glEnd()
            glPopMatrix()
```

Python returns this error:

```
            File "../libtatlin/actors.py", line 553, in draw_facets
                    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
                File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-py3.8.egg/OpenGL/latebind.py", line 43, in __call__
                    return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
                File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-py3.8.egg/OpenGL/wrapper.py", line 818, in wrapperCall
                    storeValues(
                File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-py3.8.egg/OpenGL/arrays/arrayhelpers.py", line 156, in __call__
                    contextdata.setValue( self.constant, pyArgs[self.pointerIndex] )
                File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-py3.8.egg/OpenGL/contextdata.py", line 58, in setValue
                    context = getContext( context )
                File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-py3.8.egg/OpenGL/contextdata.py", line 40, in getContext
                    raise error.Error(
            OpenGL.error.Error: Attempt to retrieve context when no valid context
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: How do you create the OpenGL context (window)? The OpenGL context has to be created before the very first OpenGL instruction.

Comment: Why do you try to mix `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences with `glDrawArrays`?

Comment: How can I create the context? What do you mean by "try to mix glBegin  / glEnd"?

Comment: There are many different ways to create an `OpenGL` context.  You'll probably get more help with this if you edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Programming in OpenGL is like programming in C: it's very low level, it's easy to shoot yourself in the foot, but if you work at it, you can achieve amazing things.
If you don't understand what a context is, or what's wrong with mixing glBegin/glEnd and glDrawArrays, you need to work through an OpenGL tutorial, eg the OpenGL SuperBible book.

I suggest looking at ModernGL, a Python package (available through PyPi / GitHub) for creating simple 3D graphical applications.